# Removing 0 values from dc js aggregated data table

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a table with aggregated data that groups on two columns and gets its data from a fake crossfilter dimension:

```
var  groupedDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date + "/./" +d.Supplier})
    .group().reduceSum(function (d) {return +d.total;});
```

I cannot get the table to hide rows with 0-values when it is crossfiltered, though. For example, I have tried to tack another fake group onto the fake dimension to get rid of the 0's but that threw an error.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zks59ndm/2/ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, does anybody know why sorting the table in ascending order throws an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are actually related problems: the data table is expecting a crossfilter dimension for its `dimension()` parameter, and groups and fake groups don't supply all the methods that the data table expects.

Looking at the browser debug console is a great way to diagnose these problems. For example, adding:

```
    .dimension(remove_empty_bins(groupedDimension))
```

results in the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _chart.dimension(...).top is not a function
```

So it wants `.top()` as well as `.all()`, glad to oblige:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    function non_zero_pred(d) {
        return d.value != 0;
    }
    return {
        all: function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(non_zero_pred);
        },
        top: function(n) {
            return source_group.top(Infinity)
                .filter(non_zero_pred)
                .slice(0, n);
        }
    };
}
```

This is [from the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#-but-i-need-top)... I know, it's become a hefty tome by now.

You almost never have to supply `.top()` - up through 2.0.* it's needed for capped charts and data tables only. As of 2.1.* it's only needed for data tables.

That brings us to the other question: why does `d3.ascending` not work?

Again, the debug console will show the way:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _chart.dimension(...).bottom is not a function
```

Ah right, in order to show them in ascending order, it wants to take the lowest N items, so now it expects the dimension to support `.bottom()`. [Here is the issue describing this problem](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1115#issuecomment-194098201), which concludes that we'd better document this somewhere or add it to the voluminous FAQ.

It also provides another workaround, the heart of which is:

```
    bottom: function(N) {
        return group.top(Infinity).slice(-N).reverse();
    }
```

That is, pull all the data in descending order, take the last N from the array, and reverse the resulting array. If we stick our nonzero-filter after `.top(Infinity)` but before `.slice(-n)`, we'll get the most stupendously over-capable `remove_empty_bins` ever!

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    function non_zero_pred(d) {
        return d.value != 0;
    }
    return {
        all: function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(non_zero_pred);
        },
        top: function(n) {
            return source_group.top(Infinity)
                .filter(non_zero_pred)
                .slice(0, n);
        },
          bottom: function(n) {
            return source_group.top(Infinity)
                .filter(non_zero_pred)
                .slice(-n).reverse();
        }
    };
}
```

Working fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5ntxvsfb/5/

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I had read most of the material you presented here but just couldn't connect the dots. One quick followup question: is there any significant performance benefit in using the 'normal' remove_empty_bins function for the other groups instead of this monster?

Comment: No there should be no performance difference. It only adds `top` and `bottom`; `.all()` is exactly the same. Just ungainly. :-/

Comment: Wow, lost days trying until I found this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad these old crossfilter and dc.js answers are still helpful to people!